# Urgent help need on sharepoint list update with Power Automate

Tags: power-automate, powerapps-canvas

I am creating a Leave Request Form in PowerApps, added Power Automate flow. Everything working fine.

Now, I need to update my LeaveBalance List (AppliedLeave Column) with the data from Leave List(TotalDays column) once the Leave is approved.

[image]

Need your urgent help and advice on this please.

Regards

Comment: Unless there is some more complexity I am missing, why don't you just use a power automate triggered on the updating of the list item, check to see if the status is approved and if so updated the value in the leave balance?

Comment: I have created a flow, but not working. I could be wrong, if you please guide.